# How to save all filter records in pdf using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

| ID | Name | Class | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Patil Priya M | 1st | 01-11-2022 |
| 1001 | Patil Priya M | 1st | 02-11-2022 |
| 1002 | Pawar Pooja N | 2nd | 01-11-2022 |
| 1002 | Pawar Pooja N | 2nd | 02-11-2022 |

**Code:**

```
  Dim table As New PdfPTable(4)
        table.TotalWidth = 416.0F
        table.LockedWidth = False
        Dim widths As Single() = New Single() {1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F, 4.0F}
        table.SetWidths(widths)
        table.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        table.SpacingBefore = 20.0F
        table.SpacingAfter = 30.0F
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Table Batch"))
        cell.Colspan = 4
        cell.Border = 0
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1
        table.AddCell(cell)
        Dim connect As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
            Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
            Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("D:\pdf\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
            pdfDoc.Open()
            Dim query As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM where ID=@ID"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = 1001
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While rdr.Read()
                        table.AddCell(rdr(0).ToString())
                        table.AddCell(rdr(1).ToString())
                        table.AddCell(rdr(2).ToString())
                        table.AddCell(rdr(3).ToString())
                    End While
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            pdfDoc.Add(table)
            pdfDoc.Close()
        End Using
```

when I use numeric value"1001"

```
 cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = 1001
```

the code showing "1001" records but when I put "ID" its showing error line. I want to filter all records yet a time. Could someone help me to resolve this issue. Thank you...

Comment: *I want to filter all records yet a time* is not exactly understandable, can you rephrase that? It's also not clear what *when I put "ID"* means -- With `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1001`, based on the data you have posted, you should get two Rows. What do you want to get instead? If you want to retrieve all rows, the remove then filter (the `WHERE` clause)

Comment: @Jimi, "cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = ID" If I use 'ID' all records I mean to say '1001',1002 records save in pdf separately. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

> cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = "ID";

When use set `ID` as the value of the parameter, it sounds like you're expecting to end up with a `WHERE` clause that looks like this:

```
WHERE ID = ID
```

Which would give you all records. *That doesn't happen.* Instead, you end up with a `WHERE` clause like more like this<sup>*</sup>:

```
WHERE ID = 'ID'
```

Note the single quotes, which denotes a string literal rather than a column name. Of course, this won't match any records, since the ID fields are all numeric.

To fix this, the VB code needs to be smart enough to send one of two different queries: one with a `WHERE` clause and parameter, and one without any `WHERE` clause at all.

---

<sup>* What actually happens is a subtly different, but this is conceptually accurate enough.</sup>